Separately show number of upvotes and downvotes
Here on Meta Stack Exchange (MSE), by clicking on the net reputation of a question, we can see the number of updates and downvotes received separately.
I think this feature should be made available on all Stack Exchange sites.

It's because of server limitations that the privilege is gated: Show the vote split by default

This feature is already available on all SE sites; it just requires reputation. It's called established user and allows you to see votes.
I believe the reason you can see votes on MSE without having the reputation to earn the privilege is because the vote split is gated at 100 rep instead of the customary 1000, despite not being detailed in the help center.
